# Using formulas in a report

Tags: reporting, formula

I have a report showing Created vs Closed cases. I'm using the 
field / event = Created.,Closed.

This report shows the last 90 days and is summarized by week.

Now I want to also show the total of opened cases per day, in the same report, using the delta of created vs closed.
Meaning - if on the first day of the report (90 days ago) we had 300 opened cases, and on that day we had 40 new cases and we closed 20 existing cases, then on the second day of the report (89 days ago) the total will be 320 opened cases.

I think that maybe a formula can help me on this, but I don't know how to use it.

Is it even possible to show all these graphs in the same report?
If I display the details in a matrix format, I have all the info I want, apart from the "total" column. [image: matrix].

Can anyone help me on this matter? 
Thank you!

Comment: You can use a "Combination Chart" to display your data. I don't understand the rest of your question well enough to help you with your formula. Perhaps if you took a "stab" at creating it yourself, you might get a more useful response from someone else.

Comment: My graph is already a combination chart (created vs closed, per week - it's a column by column graph). Can I use combination charts for 3 different infos? meaning add to the column-by-column a third line graph?

Comment: Yes, you can add line graphs to combination charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement you are asking is to track the historical data as once the data is changed you cannot get the old one in this report.
You need to use Analytic Snapshot where you can have the data stored in a custom object everyday from the report with all the information you need and then report on that custom object to have the analysis of data getting accumulated everyday.

[Analytic Snapshot](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDochttps://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_about_analytic_snap.htm)

Comment: and if I separate it to 2 different reports, one which I already have (created vs closed per week) and the other to show open cases per day (based on the number of created vs number of closed). Would that be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Rachel, you can indeed find out the number of cases opened and number of cases closed on a particular day.

But it won't be possible to find out total open cases at the end of the day, as we won't be able to know how many cases were open in the org on a particular day.

I would suggest going for **Analytic Snapshots** to accomplish this.

Comment: Rachel, I hope my answer was useful to you.

Let me know if you need any further help on this.